# ReactiveUI in hybrid winForm/wpf applications

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn, reactiveui

I have this winForm applications and we are about to rewrite some of the forms with WPF. So my plan so far is to create wpf user controls and add them into classic winforms. So far so good.

Now looking at using an MVVM frame work to make life easier and I cam across Caliburn and ReactiveUI. Caliburn in this scenario is not so easy to use as it needs to be initialised at an application level in a wpf application. Does the same apply to ReactiveUI or can I make it work with a couple of wpf controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactiveUI doesn't need to be initialized at the app level by default, it should work fine with your scenario. If it doesn't, make sure to ping [the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/reactivexaml) and let me know about it!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming to this question in the future, Caliburn.Micro now has support for initialisation from anywhere (from version 1.1). See this [discussion thread](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/260738).